# Accessing a PostgreSQL server running in a VMWare virtual machine on a mac

Tags: postgresql, vmware-fusion

I am running Postgres and Bloomberg in a VM WARE Windows XP Virtual machine on a Snow Leopard Mac (bberg is sadly windows only). Here is the IP Config of the virtual machine:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : localdomain
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.179.130
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.179.2
```

Unfortunately ping in a terminal on the same mac (outside the virtual machine of course) doesn't see that IP address:

```
users-imac:~ thomasbrowne$ ping 172.16.179.130
PING 172.16.179.130 (172.16.179.130): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
```

Therefore I cannot access the Postgres database from outside the virtual machine. I am running "Share this mac's network connection (NAT)" as the network option for the virtual machine, and the Mac is hooked to the network via wifi, where it gets a dynamic IP address. Anything I should be doing? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try bridging instead of the NATing interface. Bridging means it will get an IP from the same LAN your mac is on instead of one from VMWare NATed interface.

Comment: Thanks Nikore, but then if I do that although I can ping the VM now, the VM doesn't seem to be able to see external network (cannot visit websites for example). I think has to do with WIFI

Comment: Since you are using Wifi I'm guessing this may be a laptop, make sure the network interface VMWare is binding to is your wireless network interface and not your wired network interface.  You should be able to select which you are binding to.